# Is the maximal torus a conjugacy class?

Tags: lie-groups, analytic-continuation, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and consider $T$ a maximal torus in $G$.

At [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus) I've read that $T$ is a conjugacy class of subgroups of $G$. Does it means that there exist $t \in G$ such that $T = {xtx^{-1}: x \in G}$? Where can I find a proof of this result?

The question above is motivated by this:

If $f$ is an analytic function on $T$ can I extend it to an analytic function on $G$? If the answer of the above question is affirmative, I think it sufices to take the extension of $f$ as $g(x) = f(xtx^{-1})$ for $x \in G$ and $t$ as above.

Comment: A nontrivial subgroup can never be a conjugacy class. (Prove this.) Do you know what "conjugacy class of subgroups" means? Also, **nowhere** on the Wikipedia page does it say $T$ is a conjugacy class of subgroups. Rather, it says the collection $\{\textrm{max tori }T\}$ forms a conjugacy class of subgroups.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't reading the statement correctly.

Comment: I also just checked that if $H \subset G$ is a conjugacy class, then $H = \{e\}$. =(

Do you have any idea on how to extend an analytic function defined on a maximal torus to the entire group?

Comment: Well, going outside Lie theory, you might want to look into the task of extending analytic functions of (closed) submanifolds to manifolds. Might have something to do with "partitions of unity" or whatnot; go ask a differential geometer. If you want to make use of the fact that your submanifold is a maximal torus in a Lie group, then probably representation theory will be in order to solve the problem of when and how it's possible to extend such an analytic function.

Comment: Since there are no nontrivial analytic function with compact support, I don't think partition of the unity will be useful here. But you might be right about using representation theory. I think maybe all I need is the Peter-Weyl theorem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Right, but conceivably some kind of analytic continuation could be achieved. One would want to be wary of what happens when we go around distinct loops (as in, monodromy) though. This is out of my depth.

Comment: @MaxReinholJahnke - is your function $f$ by any chance invariant under conjugation by the normalizer of $T$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't assume that $f$ is invariant under conjugation.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to use the Fourier series of $f$ do extend the function. The partial sum of the Fourier series is invariant under conjugation, isn't? I need to read more about how to restrict the characters of the group to the maximal torus and how to relate the Fourier series on the maximal torus with a series on the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Wikipedia means is that the maximal torus is only well-defined up to conjugacy. A good example worth thinking about in detail is the case $G = U(n)$. You can take $T = U(1)^n$, the diagonal matrices, to be a maximal torus, but "diagonal matrix" implicitly refers to a choice of orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and so taking a different such basis will result in a different (but conjugate) maximal torus.

The maximal torus is in some sense maximally far from being a single conjugacy class: in fact it intersects every conjugacy class. (For $U(n)$ this follows from the spectral theorem.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for reinforce that the maximal _intersects every conjugacy class_.

Comment: @Max: as for your actual question, you can try to extend a function on $T$ to a class function on $G$.

Comment: Yes, probably the point that could counteract some misapprehensions in the question is that a fixed maximal torus meets every conjugacy class. That is, given a maximal torus, every conjugacy class has a representative (not quite unique!) in it.